# How to query documents where a rank_features field is missing?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a few hundred thousand documents. Some of them have a rank_features field called `my_field`. I want to retrieve documents without that field.

I tried:

```
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                    {"exists": {"field":"my_field"}}]
...
```

But I get the following error:

```
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "query_shard_exception",
                "reason": "failed to create query: [rank_features] fields do not support [exists] queries",
...
```

The index mapping is defined as follows:

```
        "mappings": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "_routing": {
                "required": true
            },
            "properties": {
                "my_field": {
                    "properties": {
                        "my_subfield": {
                            "type": "rank_features"
                        }
                    }
...
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "routing": {
                    "allocation": {
                        "include": {
                            "_tier_preference": "data_content"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "mapping": {
                    "total_fields": {
                        "limit": "2000"
                    }
                },
                "refresh_interval": "1s",
                "number_of_shards": "10",
                "blocks": {
                    "write": "false"
                },
```

Note that despite the mapping being strict, this field was added recently and older documents don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

You are doing a `exist` query against a field that only support `rank_feature` queries

As per the documentation of the [rank_features field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rank-features.html).

> `rank_features` fields do not support `sorting` or `aggregating` and may only be queried using `rank_feature` queries.

Comment: Is there a way to craft a `rank_features` query to check for empty/missing `rank_features`?